How to Serialize an Array of Values in a Delphi FMX File?
I am working with a Delphi FMX application and need to add a new property to one of my components. The property is an array of TAlphaColor, defined as Colors: TArray<TAlphaColor>;. I am curious about how this property would be represented in the component's paired .fmx file. Specifically, I'm looking to understand if it's possible to store an array of values like Colors: [125487, 159875] directly in the .fmx file, and if so, how this is typically done.
From what I've researched, it seems that TPropertyEditor could be related to handling custom properties in the IDE, but I'm not sure if it also influences how properties are stored or read from .fmx files. As far as I understand, TPropertyEditor is mainly for adding a custom editor within the IDE and not necessarily for modifying how data is serialized or deserialized in .fmx files.
Questions:

Is it possible to serialize an array of TAlphaColor directly in a .fmx file?
If yes, how can I format the array in the .fmx file to ensure correct loading and saving of the property?

Any guidance or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated!

Update:
I tried implementing the solution suggested by Remy Lebeau, with a slight modification: I used WriteListBegin/WriteListEnd and ReadListBegin/ReadListEnd. This approach works perfectly well when the property is directly on the root of the component, as shown below:
TALRectangle = class(TPersistent)
private
  FColors: TArray<TAlphaColor>;
  procedure ReadColors(Reader: TReader);
  procedure WriteColors(Writer: TWriter);
protected
  procedure DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler); override;
published
  property Colors: TArray<TAlphaColor> read FColors write SetColors stored IsColorsStored;
end;

// In the FMX file:
object ALRectangle1: TALRectangle
  Colors = (
    123456,
    123457
  )
end;

However, when the property is set in a child component, such as in the following structure:
TALGradient = class(TPersistent)
private
  FColors: TArray<TAlphaColor>;
  procedure ReadColors(Reader: TReader);
  procedure WriteColors(Writer: TWriter);
protected
  procedure DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler); override;
published
  property Colors: TArray<TAlphaColor> read FColors write SetColors stored IsColorsStored;
end;

TALBrush = class(TPersistent)
private
  FGradient: TALGradient;
published
  property Gradient: TALGradient read FGradient write SetGradient;
end;

TALRectangle = class(TALControl)
private
  FFill: TALBrush;
public
  property Fill: TALBrush read FFill write SetFill;
end;

// In the FMX file:
object ALRectangle1: TALRectangle
  Fill.Gradient.Colors = (
    123456,
    123457
  )
end;

But this setup fails miserably when I try to read the property as demonstrated.

What could be the issue with the nested property serialization?

Why not store all these TAlphaColor values in an image instead in dynamic array. This way you avoid the need to design custom DFM/FMX streaming code since saving and loading image into DFM/FMX is already supported. Not to mention you also gain possibility to load all of your TAlphaColor values from an external file. You would still need to design custom editor which would allow you to edit each TAlphaColor value separately. Also both VCL and FMX TBitmap classes support directly accessing to image data which means you can still achieve high performance.

hmm, thanks but the solution of @remy lebeu seam not so hard to implement ...

Making a custom Property Editor has no influence on the DFM/FMX streaming system.  Designing and Streaming are two separate operations.
DFM/FMX streaming simply does not natively support dynamic arrays.  So, you would have to stream the array data manually instead.  You can have your component override the virtual TComponent.DefineProperties() method to call either TFiler.DefineProperty() or TFiler.DefineBinaryProperty() so you can provide reader/writer callbacks for your array data, eg:
type
  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FColors: TArray<TAlphaColor>;
    procedure ReadColors(Reader: TReader);
    procedure WriteColors(Writer: TWriter);
    ...
  protected
    procedure DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler); override;
    ...
  public
    property Colors: TArray<TAlphaColor> read FColors write FColors;
    ...
  end;

procedure TMyComponent.DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler);
begin
  inherited;
  Filer.DefineProperty('Colors', ReadColors, WriteColors, FColors <> nil);
end;

procedure TMyComponent.ReadColors(Reader: TReader);
var
  I, Len: Integer;
begin
  Len := Reader.ReadInteger;
  SetLength(FColors, Len);
  for I := Low(FColors) to High(FColors) do
    FColors[I] := Reader.ReadInteger;
end;

procedure TMyComponent.WriteColors(Writer: TWriter);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Writer.WriteInteger(Length(FColors));
  for I := Low(FColors) to High(FColors) do
    Writer.WriteInteger(FColors[I]);
end;

Or:
type
  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FColors: TArray<TAlphaColor>;
    procedure ReadColors(Stream: TStream);
    procedure WriteColors(Stream: TStream);
    ...
  protected
    procedure DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler); override;
    ...
  public
    property Colors: TArray<TAlphaColor> read FColors write FColors;
    ...
  end;

procedure TMyComponent.DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler);
begin
  inherited;
  Filer.DefineBinaryProperty('Colors', ReadColors, WriteColors, FColors <> nil);
end;

procedure TMyComponent.ReadColors(Stream: TStream);
var
  Len: Integer;
begin
  Stream.ReadBuffer(Len, sizeof(Len));
  SetLength(FColors, Len);
  if Len > 0 then
    Stream.ReadBuffer(FColors[0], sizeof(TAlphaColor) * Len);
end;

procedure TMyComponent.WriteColors(Stream: TStream);
var
  Len: Integer;
begin
  Len := Length(FColors);
  Stream.WriteBuffer(Len, sizeof(Len));
  if Len > 0 then
    Stream.WriteBuffer(FColors[0], sizeof(TAlphaColor) * Len);
end;


However, I question why you want to expose a dynamic array like this in the first place.  A TCollection holding TCollectionItem objects which have a singular TAlphaColor property would probably make more sense in this case, as both the IDE and the streaming system natively support collections.  It is just as much work, probably more, to create a custom Property Editor AND custom DFM/FMX streaming, than to just setup a custom TCollection and let the IDE/streamer handle the items for you, eg:
type
  TMyColorItem = class(TCollectionItem)
  private
    FColor: TAlphaColor;
  published
    property Color: TAlphaColor read FColor write FColor;
  end;
  
  TMyColors = class(TOwnedCollection)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); reintroduce;
  end;

  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FColors: TMyColors;
    procedure SetColors(AValue: TMyColors);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Colors: TMyColors read FColors write SetColors;
  end;

constructor TMyColors.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(TMyColorItem);
end;

constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FColors := TMyColors.Create(Self);
end;

destructor TMyComponent.Destroy;
begin
  FColors.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyComponent.SetColors(AValue: TMyColors);
begin
  FColors.Assign(AValue);
end;

If you absolutely needed to work with a TArray elsewhere in your code, you could always create additional methods (or a non-published property) in your component to convert TMyColors to TArray and vice versa.

Thanks Remy, I understand about TCollection, but TCollection is for some reasons not very convenable for my need. thanks again for your answer !

your answer look perfect, but i still have a problem to implement it. I have updated the question to explain in details why it's not working with me, if you have any ideas ?

@zeus The code you showed is missing constructors and destructors for the various objects (unless you just omitted them here), and the TALRectangle.Fill property needs to be published instead of public. But also, the Colors property can't be published since the streaming system doesn't handle dynamic arrays. Changing the Colors property to public fixes the error. It will still be streamed due to DefineProperties(). I have updated my answer to reflect this. Your custom property editor can still expose items to edit the array.
